# AWS: Connections drops after scp to ec2 instance. Have to stop/start ec2 insdtance to reeconnect

Tags: scp, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

New to AWS:
I ssh into my ec2 instance without issue until I use scp to copy files from another Linux box. 5 seconds after the transfer the connection is closed and the ec2 instance needs to be stopped and started before I can ssh back into it. Reboot doesn't work it must stop and then start again.

What would cause this to be able to transfer but then be completely shutout of the instance

Comment: What files are you copying, and where are you copying them to on the ec2 instance? How large are the files?

Comment: Can you try a different AWS region, or another availability zone? See if the issue exists.

Comment: @Kenster, Text files,the files were small, less than a MB. The files were being copied to the ec2-users home directory. I copied them from remote Linux box that i use.

Comment: ISP installed new service and listed ssh access as a threat. Disabled ISP security on CM. Issue resolved